# Cy.wait() doesn't seem to be working the same way after version 7

Tags: cypress

I am in the process of upgrading from Cypress version 6.5 to version 8.0 (but this issue was present when I was trying to upgrade to 7.2 last month and gave up) and encountering issues with tests that were passing earlier. I reviewed the migration guide and made the appropriate updates, but there are some request behaviors that seem to be functioning differently.

Take the following example. When a user navigates to the "delete" page of the admin panel for this workout item, there is a GET request that automatically fires for the fitness plan. Prior to the update, this request never blocked anything, but now my other checks run without waiting for these requests to fire. See image below:
[image: Failing test]
You can see there's a gap between when the xhr and the actual request fires that matches my wait. (Which, side question -- what is the difference between the xhr and the req in Cypress? Why are they always paired?)

If I add a 5 second wait, and remove the intercept waits, we see this passes:
[image: passing with wait]

The code:

```
cy.getBySel('workout-radio-delete').click();
    cy.getBySel('workout-find').click();
    cy.contains('Search').click();
    cy.getBySel('fitnessModal-workoutCard')
      .contains('Alternate Workout')
      .click();
    cy.getBySel('workoutModal-submit').click();
    cy.getBySel('workout-recordRows').should('have.length', 1);
    cy.wait('@getFitnessPlan')
    cy.getBySel('workout-submit').click();
    cy.wait('@updateWorkout')
    cy.getBySel('workout-message-success').should(
      'have.text',
      'Workout "Alternate Workout" was deleted successfully!'
    );
```

And here's what it was like with version 6.5 (Note that there are no waits in this version because they weren't needed, I added the waits in version 7+ because it was failing without them -- of course it's still failing with them)
[image: passing version 6.5]

Comment: There's a PUT request that occurs after clicking the Submit button in your screenshots of the passing tests that's not in your first screenshot. I assume this request is necessary in order for your tests to pass. Have you tried calling `cy.wait` on it? (And for your side question, the `xhr`'s are "live" and not intercepted by Cypress, whereas the `req`'s are HTTP calls that are caught by Cypress, if I recall correctly.)

Comment: The PUT request is the cy.wait('@updateWorkout') but as you can see it never gets to that request -- the checks just go right ahead and run before the request has even fired (it's still firing the GET request on the fitness plan in the first image)

Comment: Ah ok. I believe I had a similar problem. The only advice I can give is to make sure you're not intercepting the same route an unnecessary number of times.